# How to Read drop down list values from excel using apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to check which columns in excel have drop down values and read those values in a list of string. I am using Apache POI library.
I did some research and found it can be done using `public abstract String[] getExplicitListValues()` method of `DataValidationConstraint` interface.
But I am not sure how to use it in the code. Can someone please help?

Comment: Looking to similar issue but no luck till now. Have you find out some way out.

Comment: I have figured out a way to read drop down list from Apache POI using HSSFWorkBook.

Check out answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181551/read-drop-down-list-content-from-excel-using-apache-poi/21677555#21677555

Answer (score 0):

```
    CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(
            0, 0, 0, 0);
    DVConstraint dvConstraint = DVConstraint.createExplicitListConstraint(
            new String[]{"10", "20", "30"});
    DataValidation dataValidation = new HSSFDataValidation
            (addressList, dvConstraint);
    dataValidation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(false);
    sayfa1.addValidationData(dataValidation);
```