# Read drop down list content from Excel using apache poi

Tags: java, android, apache-poi

I need to create a drop down list (Data Validation) on a particular cell in an Excel sheet and read them back.

With the help of tutorials provided by `Apache POI`, I am able to create a Drop-down list in an Excel sheet, but I also need to read the drop-down list content when reading that again, so that I can render a similar drop-down list on a UI.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DataValidation is stored even in HSSF workbook, but it is in `Internal Sheet` of the library and since it is `private` so access to it is not given to application programmer.
I have used Java Reflection API to access internal sheet. 
This code is working fine for me.

```
private ArrayList<DVRecord> init(FileInputStream fis) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    HSSFWorkbook hWorkbook = (HSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
    HSSFSheet hSheet = hWorkbook.getSheetAt(1); // sheet on which you want to read data validation
    Class c = org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet.class;
    Field field = c.getDeclaredField("_sheet");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    Object internalSheet = field.get(hSheet);
    InternalSheet is = (InternalSheet) internalSheet;
    DataValidityTable dvTable = is.getOrCreateDataValidityTable();
    Class c2 = org.apache.poi.hssf.record.aggregates.DataValidityTable.class;
    Field field2 = c2.getDeclaredField("_validationList");
    field2.setAccessible(true);
    Object records = field2.get(dvTable);
    ArrayList<DVRecord> dvRecords = (ArrayList<DVRecord>) records;
    return dvRecords;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code @GauravGupta. How can I set/select a value from the drop down (datavalidation list) using poi.

Answer (score 7):

I can't seem to find any mechanism in HSSF to retrieve the `DataValidation`s from the `HSSFSheet`.  So if you have a .xls file, you're out of luck.

However, if you have a .xlsx file, then `XSSFSheet` supplies a method to retrieve a list of all `XSSFDataValidation`s on the sheet: [`getDataValidations`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#getDataValidations()), which returns a `List<XSSFDataValidation>`.

You'll need to loop over them all, calling [`regions()`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFDataValidation.html#getRegions()) to examine the `CellRangeAddressList` to see if it applies to your cell.  If it does, then call [`getValidationConstraint`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFDataValidation.html#getValidationConstraint()) to access the `DataValidationConstraint` object, on which you can call [`getExplicitListValues`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataValidationConstraint.html#getExplicitListValues()) to get the array of strings back.

Comment: I was able to read DataValidation using HSSF workbook, i have used reflection API to get the validation list.

Comment: I have a `XSSFSheet`, unfortunately it returns an empty `ArrayList`, even though I have dropdown lists defined. Not sure why.