# Not able to read the drop down list value from excel using POI java

Tags: java, apache-poi

[image]

I am not able to read the data for the cell company code and the drop down value for it. I tried reading the data using

try {

```
        Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(
                "D:/TCA/Test/test.xlsx"));
        // org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new
        // FileInputStream("D:/TCA/Test/aa.xlsx"));
        for (int i = 0; i < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
            Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(i);
            Name name = null;

            System.out.println(wb.getSheetName(i));
            for (Row row : sheet) {

                name = sheet.getWorkbook().createName();

                // System.out.println("rownum: " + row.getRowNum());

                for (Cell cell : row) {
                    // System.out.println(cell);

                    handleCell(cell.getCellType(), cell);
                }

            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

Comment: What does `handleCell` do? Do you get any exception?

Comment: look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181551/read-drop-down-list-content-from-excel-using-apache-poi)

Comment: its a method where i will check for type like CELL_TYPE_STRING,CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC etc and will print the cell.getStringCellValue()