# Excel read dropdown options using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm reading and evaluating an excel file with POI. I need to read the dropdowns from the file and display them as an HTML form element.

I can read the current value from the cell that contains a dropdown, but I can't get the list of all the other possible values.

As per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181551/read-drop-down-list-content-from-excel-using-apache-poi/21677555#21677555) I tried using the DataValidations class to read the dropdown, but I think this is only for setting validations and not getting them. The [DataValueConstraint.getExplicitListValues()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181551/read-drop-down-list-content-from-excel-using-apache-poi/21677555#21677555) method returned an empty list.

**Does anyone know how to get the dropdown values? Can you show me some code that just prints the list of values?**

Comment: Maybe there are not explicit list values but a formula which points to a list range?

Comment: Ahh. I think your onto someting @AxelRichter

Comment: @noel did you found solution to this..??