# How to read drop list items in excel cell value?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have saved contact details of the same type in the same cell(e.g person has more than one email address) I have saved them as a list in one cell but I'm not able to read them when iterating through my excel sheet. I can only read the currently selected/displayed, other options are ignored. I'm using java

```
//Read sheet inside the workbook by its name

Sheet _workSheet = _workbook.getSheet(sheetName);

//Iterate through each rows
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = _workSheet.iterator();

while(rowIterator.hasNext())
{
    //Get Each Row
    Row row_ = rowIterator.next();

    //Iterator through each column of each row
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row_.cellIterator();

    while(cellIterator.hasNext())
    {
        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();                         

        //Checking the cell format
        switch(cell.getCellType())
        {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue()+"\n");
                break;

            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue()+"\n");
                break;

            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                System.out.println(cell.getBooleanCellValue()+"\n");
                break;

            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                System.err.println(cell.getStringCellValue()+" .....empty cell");
                break;
        }
    }
    System.err.println("");

}
```

In cell "A2" I'm expecting to get two values (emailone, emailTwo)

Comment: What kind of list in one cell are you talking about? Is this a data validation list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read drop down list content from Excel using apache poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181551/read-drop-down-list-content-from-excel-using-apache-poi)

Comment: Thanks,These did the trick.



List<XSSFDataValidation> dataValidations = sheet.getDataValidations();
            Iterator<XSSFDataValidation> iterator = dataValidations.iterator();
            XSSFDataValidation dataValidation = iterator.next();
            String[] explicitListValues = dataValidation.getValidationConstraint().getExplicitListValues();

Answer (score 0):

```
These did the trick;
List<XSSFDataValidation> dataValidations = sheet.getDataValidations();
            Iterator<XSSFDataValidation> iterator = dataValidations.iterator();
            XSSFDataValidation dataValidation = iterator.next();
            String[] explicitListValues = dataValidation.getValidationConstraint().getExplicitListValues();
```